# Change TAB backcolor or Letters color in DEVSTYLE theme

Tags: eclipse, themes

I use DEVSTYLES with the DARKEST MODE in themes but the words in TABs are almost the same and cannot been seen as you can see below.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Can someone help me?
Thanks
PS. I change to the Eclipse Dark theme but still the Carets(>) in every menu almost cannot been seen as you can see below.
Is there any way to change the color?
[image]

Comment: Some of these theme add-ons do all sorts of hideous messing around. I find the standard Eclipse dark mode is perfectly fine without add-ons.

Comment: We've been unable to reproduce this with our Darkest Dark theme. Are those editor tabs - do other tabs in the workspace, like view tabs, look the same too? Have you customized the theme in any way? Do let us know what OS you're on and what version and distribution of Eclipse you're using so we can try to reproduce the problem and get a fix in. Thanks!

Comment: **BRIAN FERNANDES**, it was a new installation on my new laptop with Windows 10 and Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers 2021-12. I am using ATD Tools for ABAP. ALL TABs are the same.

Comment: @howlger I did it but as you can see I have problems also with the Dark theme of the Eclipse. As you can see the arrow **>** almost are invisible as well as the menu item that has the focus (**General**) in our case. Any idea how can I fix them? Thanks

Comment: @ekekakos Uninstall the plugin (disabling it is not enough). If the problem persists, use a fresh workspace (without copying the settings from the old one). You are not the first to have such issues. Unfortunately, the vendor of the plugin seems to be more successful in removing of questions, answers and comments about such issues than in removing the issues.

Comment: @ekekakos apologies, missed your response. We have tried ADT on Eclipse - specifically your versions, and have not been able to reproduce this coloring problem. Clearly something is wrong though - were you using any themes prior to DevStyle, in the same workspace?

Comment: Please be aware that this plugin tries to cheat the Eclipse open source license by patching Eclipse at runtime (or to be more precise via loadtime weaving). This can cause issues and slow down Eclipse. Consider using a more ergonomic theme that doesn't have such issues if you don't like the themes built-in.

Comment: @BrianFernandes thanks for your last comment. I created a new workspace and all themes are working perfect. I copy the plugins *.recources* (2) in it by replacing the ones that created and this one is working perfect as the old one. Thanks again.

Comment: @ekekakos that's awesome, glad you are up and running, and thank you for letting me know!